# C++; loop with randomizing array keys not working

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, random

I am stuck with a problem that I originally thought would be so easy to solve!

I have an enum with 4 values (empty, male, female, child). I have an array which corresponds to 50 seats. So, I would like to put men, women, and children in the empty seats based on a randomly generated seat number. If the seat is not empty, then the program should continue to search for other empty seats.

This is what I have:

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <ctime>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

    enum pax {E, M, F, C};
    pax seats[50] = {E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E,
                    E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E};

    int paxNumMaleTotal;    // Total number of Male passengers Loaded
    int paxNumFemaleTotal;
    int paxNumChildTotal;

    void random(int j);


    int main()  {


    // Randomize seating for Male

    int n=1;
    int i=0;
    paxNumMaleTotal=35;
    paxNumFemaleTotal=8;
    paxNumChildTotal=5;

        while (n<= paxNumMaleTotal)  {  // loop until all men take their seats

            while (seats[i] != M || seats[i] != F || seats[i] != C)   {  
                   // take a seat unless the seat is not occupied
                 random(i);                 // generate a random seat to be taken
                 seats[i] = M;              // Seat is taken by a man
            }
            n++;  // seat is taken, take the next one

         }


     for (int k=0; k<50; k++)  {     // printing the seating chart
        cout << seats[k] << endl;
        }
 }

 void random(int j)     // this is the function that gives a random seat number
 {
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    j = rand() % 50;
 }
```

So, I tried all possible options. It either puts men in all 50 seats or, like in this case, put a man in the first seat with no loop. Thanks a lot for your time!

Thanks for your help. Using the reference, I solved the issue of randomly selecting a seat. A problem with the loop is  still here. It selects only one seat (randomly) and not 35 seats. :-(

---

EDIT: Thank you! The random_shuffle function did the trick!

```
for (int i=0; i < paxNumMaleTotal; i++)    {
        seats[i] = M;
}

for (int i = paxNumMaleTotal; i < paxNumFemaleTotal + paxNumMaleTotal; i++)    {
        seats[i] = F;
}

for (int i=paxNumFemaleTotal + paxNumMaleTotal; i < paxNumFemaleTotal + paxNumMaleTotal +
                            paxNumChildTotal; i++)  {
        seats[i] = C;
}

// Randomize seating for passengers
std::random_shuffle (&seats[0], &seats[49]);
```

Comment: srand() should only be called once an application. Call it once just after main() starts.

Comment: It might be simpler to fill the seats with the desired number of men/women/children and then use [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) to randomize their positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, others have pointed out the small error in your random function signature.

There's probably an easier way to do this though.  First, fill your array with the correct proportion of passengers.  Just do this in order with a couple of for loops, or something fancier if you like.

Then use std::random_shuffle.  It gives you a [very reliable shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).  There are lots of ways to [get it wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Comparison_with_other_shuffling_algorithms), so it's good to use the well-tested algorithm.. :)

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
srand( time( NULL ) );
j = rand() % 50;
```

is the problem. time(NULL) has 1 second resolution. This seeds your random generator to almost always the same value, because the outer loop is much faster than one second.

Solution: Initialize your random generator only once at the beginning of the program.

Additionally: your assignement to `j` has no effect. You modify a *copy* of the argument and this copy is never returned.

Answer (score 4):

Your `random()` function does not return anything. You probably meant passing j by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Presently your `random()` function does not return anything.

Try this:-

```
void random(int &j)
```

**EDIT:-**

Try to use [std::random_shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) to randomize the position after filling the desired setas with men/women

Answer (score 1):

Send parameter by ref

```
void random(int &j);

void random(int &j)
{
   j = rand() % 50;
}
```

call

> srand( time( NULL ) );

in main.

Good luck.